# Email Sent Using AppScript Appears in Sent Box, but does not appear in Recipient's Inbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using AppsScript to send emails by prompts on GoogleSheets.  When I test the AppScript, the email appears in my Sent box; however, it does not appear in the recipients inbox.

I have tried manually sending the same email; it appears in my Sent box and does appear in the recipient's inbox.  I do not understand how an email can appear in by Sent via both AppScript and Manually, yet only the manual email appears in the recipient's inbox.

Comment: We can't help you unless you provide the [mcve]